# Get details of uninstalled Windows fonts via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, fonts, imagemagick

I'm using PowerShell and ImageMagick to create customized images of my font collection to determine which fonts I want to install into the system.  I'd like to have the image include some font information, but I am having a difficult time extracting that information.  I found some useful code at https://powershell.org/forums/topic/listing-font-details/#post-78006, but I found that information is only accessible *within* the system's font directory.  My collection exists **outside** of `%SystemRoot%\Fonts`.

I'd like to access things like

- font name (Aparajita)
- font style (bold, normal, italic)
- font type (Raster, OpenType/TrueType)

etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing Theo's answer, and doing some code modification, I made the discovery that there are different extended attributes depending on if the font is installed or not.
The top section of the following output is when the font is installed, versus the bottom section when it is not installed.  In short, if I want to embed the 'Font Style' and 'Designed For' into the image Im generating, I need to install the font first.

```
Value                                           Attribute                      Index
-----                                           ---------                      -----
Regular                                         Font style                         1
Show                                            Show/hide                          2
Arabic                                          Designed for                       3
Text                                            Category                           4
Microsoft Corporation                           Designer/foundry                   5
Editable                                        Font embeddability                 6
OpenType                                        Font type                          7
Arabic Typesetting                              Family                             8
‎2013-‎Aug-‎22 ‏‎11:34 A                             Date modified                     10
505 KB                                          Size                              11
C:\Windows\Fonts\ARABTYPE.TTF                   Font file names                   13
6.00                                            Font version                      14
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
609 KB                                          Size                               1
TrueType font file                              Item type                          2
2009-Jun-10 04:43 P                             Date modified                      3
2019-Dec-16 01:50 P                             Date created                       4
2019-Dec-16 01:50 P                             Date accessed                      5
A                                               Attributes                         6
Available offline                               Availability                       8
Unspecified                                     Perceived type                     9
Everyone                                        Owner                             10
Unrated                                         Rating                            19
Mamoun Sakkal, Paul C. Nelson and John Hudson   Authors                           20
Arabic Typesetting                              Title                             21
© 2008 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Res... Copyright                         25
94.9 GB                                         Total size                        50
WINDOWS8.1 (this PC)                            Computer                          53
.ttf                                            File extension                   156
arabtype.ttf                                    Filename                         157
5.91                                            File version                     158
1.81 GB                                         Space free                       161
No                                              Shared                           178
Fonts                                           Folder name                      181
Y:\Documents\Fonts                              Folder path                      182
Fonts (Y:\Documents)                            Folder                           183
Y:\Documents\Fonts\arabtype.ttf                 Path                             185
TrueType font file                              Type                             187
Unresolved                                      Link status                      193
‎98%                                             Space used                       242
Not shared                                      Sharing status                   282
Available                                       <unknown>                        283
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Shell.Application` COM object to get details of files is not limited to the `%SystemRoot%\Fonts` folder.

If you have a folder on disk where you keep your collection of fonts, you could use the below code to get information for each of the font files:

```
function Get-FontInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([Psobject])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
        [string]$SourceFolder,
        [switch]$Recurse
    )
    # using a lookup hashtable to avoid localized field names
    $fontProperties = [ordered]@{
        0   = 'Name'
        1   = 'Size'
        2   = 'Type'
        20  = 'Author'
        21  = 'Title'
        25  = 'Copyright'
        33  = 'Company'
        34  = 'Description'
        164 = 'Extension'
        165 = 'FileName'
        166 = 'Version'
        194 = 'Path'
        196 = 'FileType'
        310 = 'Trademark'
    }
    $shell  = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    $objDir = $shell.NameSpace($SourceFolder)
    $files  = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter '*.*' -File -Recurse:$Recurse

    foreach($file in $files) {
        $objFile   = $objDir.ParseName($file.Name)
        $mediaFile = $objDir.Items()
        $output    = [ordered]@{}
        $fontProperties.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            $name  = $objDir.GetDetailsOf($mediaFile, $_.Name)
            if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name)) { 
                $output[$_.Value] = $objDir.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $_.Name)
            }
        }
        [PsCustomObject]$output
    }

    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objFile)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDir)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

Get-FontInfo -SourceFolder 'D:\Test'  # the path of the font folder
```

If you have subfolders inside the source folder, also add the `-Recurse` switch.

Output something like:

```
Name        : aparaj.ttf
Size        : 194 kB
Type        : TrueType-lettertypebestand
Author      : 
Title       : Aparajita
Copyright   : Copyright (c) 2011, Modular Infotech, Pune, INDIA. - Licenced to Microsoft
Company     : 
Description : This font is primarily meant for use in displaying Hindi text in documents. It is an OpenType font, based on Unicode. 
Extension   : .ttf
FileName    : aparaj.ttf
Version     : 6.00
Path        : D:\Test\aparaj.ttf
FileType    : TrueType-lettertypebestand
Trademark   :
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems my font files are lacking some of this information.

Comment: Ah, I see why, the hash lookup is different.  ie: you have 194 for Path, whereas mine is 185.  exFAT on Win8.